# MSG command from java 32 applicaiton not working in 64 bit win 7/ win 2008 server

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64, msg

I am using MSG command[NETSEND is no longer available] to send message from Win 7/2008 server(32/64 bit) to Win 7/2008 server(32/64 bit) and my java application is 32 bit and cannot use 64 bit due to certain requirements(using java 7 update 25). 
When I run my java application below are the scenario

1. 32 bit Win 7/2008 server to 32 bit Win 7/2008 - working
2. 32 bit Win 7/2008 server to 64 bit Win 7/2008 - working
3. 32 bit Win 7/2008 server to 64 bit Win 7/2008 - working

   **4. 64 bit Win 7/2008 server to 64 bit Win 7/2008 - NOT working**

   **5. 64 bit Win 7/2008 server to 32 bit Win 7/2008 - NOT working**

Is there any workaround to make this work in 64 bit Win 7/2008 server?

```
package msgcommand;

import java.io.*;  
public class TestExec {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try {  
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C MSG.exe /SERVER:127.0.0.1 * test");  
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
            String line = null;  
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                System.out.println(line);  
            }  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem is, that on an 64-bit System a 32-bit application cannot access the windows\system32 folder. You will redi

To reach the 32-bit version auf the msg.exe you can use the special folder **%WinDir%\Sysnative** to execute the msg.exe

Details are available here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942589/en-us